# How to add one more child to a has_many association and run call backs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models Invoice and Shipment. Invoice has_many shipments and a shipment belongs_to a Invoice.

Here is what i am trying to do.

Create a new shipment.

```
new_shipment = Shipment.create! (params)
```

Check if a invoice already exists for the contract of this shipment.

```
invoice = Invoice.find_by_ref_no(ref_no)

if invoice.nil?
    invoice.shipments << new_shipment
    invoice.save
else
    Invoice.create! (some_params,
                    :shipment_ids => [new_shipment.id],
                    other_params   
                    )
end
```

I want to know that do i need to save the invoice after adding shipment?
Further how can I directly add shipment without fetching it first?

I use :before_save and :after_save in Invoice to do some processing. In console I tried something like this.

```
Invoice.last.shipments << (Shipment.first)
Invoice.last.shipments.count
```

And the count increased. But I am unsure whether :before_save and :after_save will run if i explicitly don't save the invoice.

Here I am importing big data from excel file so I want to make sure the I don't save invoice twice.

Comment: `invoice.shipments.create!(PARAMS_FOR_SHIPMENT)`...may be you want this...thanks

Comment: I don't have all the existing shipments of that invoice. It's a new shipment which has just been created and it needs to be added to an existing invoice(Not create a new invoice).

Comment: no you donot have require all shipments for creating shipments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The association between invoice and shipment is saved when you do this line of code :

```
invoice.shipments << new_shipment
```

However your before_save and after_save callbacks won't be triggered until you do :

```
invoice.save
```

I think you must fetch the shipment first before assigning it. I don't think there is any way around that.

Comment: Can you tell me bit more about why child is associated but call backs don't run or give some reference to find out.

Comment: collection<<(object, …)
Adds one or more objects to the collection by creating associations in the join table (collection.push and collection.concat are aliases to this method). Note that this operation instantly fires update sql without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object, unless the parent object is a new record.

Comment: Thanks. Btw is there some way to avoid this sql update and only have one save query to add the child and then save it with one query only?

Comment: @Bot, that's impossible even with plain SQL. You have to get the id of the new record before you can make the association. You'll always need two queries for that.

Comment: I get it now! :) Thanks to both of you. Then I think how I am doing is fine.

Comment: @Mischa Wait it has to simply update invoice_id column of that shipment and run before_save and after_save of Invoice. I was searching around and found something association call backs. Something I can do with that?

Answer (score 1):

you can do while creating your shipment,

```
@new_shipment = invoice.shipments.new 
@new_shipment.save
```

,this will associate shipment to invoice.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This seems a good way but it is not necessary in my case that a shipment is always invoiced while creating it. Depending on some conditions I may or may not want to associate it to a invoice.